# How can I build rpm binary for my embedded system?

Tags: linux, rpm, powerpc

Please note that I am "not" looking to build an RPM package.

Rather, I am looking to build the rpm binary itself which I can run to install an RPM package on my system. I scoured through the web for any reference but almost all of the results were for creating an RPM package, rather than compiling 'rpm' binary.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: So you want /usr/bin/rpm for you embedded system? What architecture it is. RPM is available for a lot of architectures already.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora's RPM Guide has an entire chapter [dedicated to bootstrapping RPM on non-RPM OSs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-other-os.html). A quick glance tells me it might be a good start.